# Perform function on String of Numbers in Data Frame

Tags: r

If I have a simple data frame that has samples and numbers represented as characters like this:

```
Sample     Vals
 A         1,2,3,4,5
 B         3,4,5,6,7
 C         6,7,8
```

Such that we can convert and operate on the string as numbers (or pass to a function) to get something like the mean (or whatever).

```
Sample     Vals         Mean
 A         1,2,3,4,5    3
 B         3,4,5,6,7    5
 C         6,7,8        7
```

The challenge I'm having is with the type conversion.  For instance, I can split the vals out by

```
df$Vals<-strsplit(df$Vals, ",")
```

but converting it to a numeric or integer gets a bit tricky even with trying to use 'as.numeric', etc. Seems like a pretty straighforward thing but I tried finding a suitable answer to no avail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `base R` we can split the column by comma with `strsplit`, then find the `mean`. Be sure to set `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` when reading in the data:

```
df$Mean <- sapply(strsplit(df$Vals, ","), function(x) mean(as.numeric(x)))
df
#  Sample      Vals Mean
#1      A 1,2,3,4,5    3
#2      B 3,4,5,6,7    5
#3      C     6,7,8    7
```

Comment: ok, yes, this is helpful. I did not have my stringsAsFactors set to FALSE

Answer (score 2):

We can use `data.table`.  Grouped by 'Sample', we split the 'Vals' by `,` , convert to 'numeric' get the `mean` and assign (`:=`) it as the 'Mean' column.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[,Mean := mean(as.numeric(strsplit(Vals, ',')[[1]])) , by = Sample]
df1
#   Sample      Vals Mean
#1:      A 1,2,3,4,5    3
#2:      B 3,4,5,6,7    5
#3:      C     6,7,8    7
```

---

Or using `cSplit`, we split the 'Vals' by `,`, get the `mean` of the 'Vals', grouped by 'Sample'.

```
library(splitstackshape)
cSplit(df1, 'Vals', ',', 'long')[, list(Vals=toString(Vals), 
                       Mean=mean(Vals)) , by = Sample]
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option using `data.table` is to combine `tstrsplit` and `rowMeans` and thus avoid by row operaiotns

```
library(data.table) #V1.9.6+
setDT(df)[, Mean := rowMeans(setDT(tstrsplit(Vals, ",", type.convert = TRUE)), na.rm = TRUE)]
#    Sample      Vals Mean
# 1:      A 1,2,3,4,5    3
# 2:      B 3,4,5,6,7    5
# 3:      C     6,7,8    7
```